# Android Studio JNI/C++: how to define a root path for all #include tags?

Tags: java, android, c++, cmake, java-native-interface

I have an Android Java/C++ (JNI) project using CMake.

Here is the structure of the C++ part of my project:

[image]

So, I have different subfolders in my project (project1, project2, etc...)

The files in these folders have different #include tags. Some of the #include tags in a defined folder refer to a file in another folder. For these tags, I would like to have a #include with a path like:

```
#include "otherproject/xxx.h" // I want that !
```

and NOT like:

```
#include "../otherproject/xxx.h" // I don't want that !
```

For example, for the project1file1.h, here is what I want and don't want:

```
#include "project2/project2file1.h" // I want that !
// #include "../project2/project2file1.h" // I don't want that !
```

So, my question is : is it possible in Android Studio/C++/JNI/CMake to define a kind of root path for all #include tags ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add the directory containing the include file using `target_include_directories`.

Comment: Thanks. May you give more details about what I should write exactly in target_include_directories() in this specific example? Seems not so easy to understand how it works... Thanks.